# Returning column names from table in SQLite using Java GUI

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jcombobox

I need to get column names from table, only difference is that I made a function that makes new column depending on users entry in txtbox. So for example if a user enters "3", column would be named "Sezonalni_utjecaj_3". Now when you saw that example I need to make a query that returns column names so I can put them inside my combobox, so everytime I enter a new column, the name of the column would be placed inside of the combobox (column names have something in common, and thats "Sezonalni_utjecaj_", but I have other columns too, not only ones that have "Sezonalni_utjecaj_" inside their name but I dont need their names ).

My Interface:

[image]

When i press "Ok" this is code behind it:

```
btnOk_2 = new JButton("Ok");
    btnOk_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {
                String kolumna=(String)textField.getText();
                String upit="alter table Linearni_trend_s_sezonalnim_utjecajem add column 'Sezonalni_utjecaj_"+kolumna+"' float;";
                PreparedStatement pst1 = konekcija.prepareStatement(upit);
                pst1.execute();
                pst1.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I find it very hard to understand just what it is you are asking, what you have and what you need help with. Please consider clarifying your question including showing code, and trying to explain your problem as clearly as possible. Take your time, consider writing out a few paragraphs that go into a bit more detail regarding your code and your problem.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Will do, ill put screenshots of my interface and what explane how it works.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Hope its better for understanding now.

Comment: I've added your image, but you still need to post code as *code* not as an image, and you still will likely want to add more and better descriptive text.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I hope this is understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Pragma can help you to get all columns name with type etc etc.[PRAGMA_SQL](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)

```
  PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```

Alternatively you may use another way like ;

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
WHERE tbl_name = 'table_name' AND type = 'table'
```