# I can't get all table names in a Database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio, xiaomi

I'm just writing a program on android studio and it's about the database management. I show you to partial code of my project.

```
public ArrayList<String> getTableNames(){

    ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
            arrTblNames.add( cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("name")) );
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    return  arrTblNames;
}
```

I need all table names. The problem is that I can get first table name but then the loop is ending and the other table names are being unavailable. The problem is happened only at xiaomi phone, it's working correctly at samsung phone. Please help me to get all table names .
Thanks.

Comment: You need to make this a reproducible question.  How many tables are in your database exactly, and are you sure of this number?

Comment: Also duplicate of [*Returning column names from table in SQLite using Java GUI*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29329740/642706)